# How to structure projects containing JAXB/Moxy adapters

Tags: java, jaxb, moxy

I'm updating a fairly large project from Castor to Jaxb/Moxy. I've had to make some changes, notably moving all the non-static inner classes out of the class I'm trying to serialize and adding a set of xmlAdapters and associated mappable classes to handle "unmappable classes."

That's all fine, but since Moxy has issues "seeing" across packages, I've put all of these in the same package with my main document class and all it's associated classed.

That's no problem technically, but the package was already the largest in the project and now is even more cluttered.

I have twelve (12) classes that were previously non-static inner classes that have now been extracted and given name prefixes to identify them as a unit, and six (6)classes that are either xmlAdapters or the mappable classes they adapt to and from and will likely end up with more.

Ordinarily, I'd like to refactor these into their own folders and associated packages, but I don't want to break Moxy.

What's the best practice for both these cases and keeping projects well-organized when using Moxy?

Thanks